# I cannot access to var from child class I need to make a new request when recyclerview doesnt have more data to display

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, retrofit2, swiperefreshlayout

I am trying to access to mBeers fromd HomeViewHolder but I got this "You need to create a abstrac property" but that is not a solution because I have a base class. I need to make a new request when recyclerview doesnt have more data to display.

```
class HomeAdapter(private val beers: ArrayList<Beer>, val context: Context):
        RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseViewHolder>() {  
  
        class HomeViewHolder(itemView: View): BaseViewHolder(itemView) {
            val beerImage: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_row_image)
            val beerLayout: ConstraintLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cl_row_layout)
            val beerName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_row_name)
            val beerTagLine: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_row_name)
    
            override fun clear() {}
    
            override fun onBind(position: Int) {
                super.onBind(position)
                Picasso.get().load(mBeers!![position].imageURL).fit().centerCrop().transform(
                    RoundedCornersTransformation(10, 0)
                ).into(beerImage)
                beerName!!.text = mBeers!![position].name
                beerTagLine!!.text = mBeers!![position].tagLine
    
                beerLayout!!.setOnClickListener {
                    val intent = Intent(context, DetailActivity::class.java)
                    context!!.startActivity(intent)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You pass the array list `beers`, but you never use it. Did you mix up `mBeers` and `beers`?

Comment: Yes I did, I did a mixed up

`var mBeers: ArrayList<Beer>? = null

    init {
        mBeers = beers
    }`